# How to do autocomplete validation in Angular2?

Tags: validation, templates, angular, autocomplete

I have been trying to implement an auto-complete to an input in my form in angular2. I want to show second hidden div if the input is invalid. Could you help me how to do that please?

```
<div class="form-group">
<div *ngSwitchCase="'organisation'">
    <label [attr.for]="parameter.ObjectID" [innerHtml]="parameter.paramLabel">  </label>
    <input [id]='parameter.ObjectID' class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="parameter.value" (keyup)="filter()" (change)="filter()" (blur)="filter()" [required]="parameter.mandatory" name="mandatory" #mandatory="ngModel">
    <div *ngIf="companyNames.length > 0">
        <ul *ngFor="let item of filteredCompanyList">
            <li>
                <a (click)="select(item)">{{item}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="!parameter.mandatory || mandatory.valid || mandatory.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">Please do not leave this field blank</div>
    <div [hidden]="temp(mandatory)" class="alert alert-danger">The organisation entered was either not found or does not subscribe to the product</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second hidden div will be displayed if your function `temp()` returns false.

All your checks (input valid?) you have to do in this function.

UPDATE:

Just use this `[hidden]="filteredCompanyList.length > 0"` to show/hide your div.

Comment: First hidden div is checking if the input is empty or not. The second one is supposed to be shown when the user put the value which is not one of the specified organisations in the json file. I am looking something like ngfocus or such if there is a way to do that.

Comment: So you should use an boolean variable inside of your component! the default value is true (the div is hidden!) and after your search you will set this variable to false if there are no matches. or just use filteredCompanyList.length != 0